# input string is not in correct format (confirm delete button code behind)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to get a new line when display the message. Whats wrong with this code?

```
Button l = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnDelete");            
string textForMessage = @"<script language='javascript'> confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record \ntest\ntest\ntest');</script>";            
l.Attributes.Add("onclick", textForMessage + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Name") + ")");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to display Name in the confirmation message,
here is the proper way.

```
Button l = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnDelete");
string textForMessage = @"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record with the name: {0}');";            
l.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format(textForMessage, DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Name"));
```

There is no need of **script** blocks as string inside **onclick** quotes is known as javascript to browsers and you need to add return keywork as **return** will stops deleting event to be called.

**Edit 1** there is nothing looks wrong with \n you can add \n easily
for instance

```
string textForMessage = @"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record, \nwith the name: {0}\nsome more text lines');";
```

make sure your string started with **@** symbol, as
string textForMessage = @"message"
else you need to use double slash

Comment: how do i have `\n` ? i want to add more text to the next line

Comment: make sure you used @ symbol before starting your string message

Comment: nice copied, maybe one time you understand SO

Comment: Thanks for the compliments, suggest the site owner for a badge Code Copier. Note: but the problem was not solved by, whether I copied? but the problem solved by pointing out the actual issue.

Answer (score 1):

nono, there is something wrong there...

I think you want to do this:

```
string textForMessage = @"confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record with the name: {0}');";            
l.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format(textForMessage, DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Name"));
```

Comment: how do i have a new line? i try to use `\n` but get error when i do